# Clarification on partitioning a group into cosets

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, sylow-theory

I'm reading I. N. Herstein's proof of Sylow's third theorem:

> **Theorem:** The number of $p$-Sylow subgroups in $G$, for a given prime, is of the form $1+kp$.

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YQ5A.jpg) of the proof, for reference.

All but one part of the proof makes sense to me. First, I'm aware that double cosets form an equivalence relation in a group, so for a subgroup $P<G$ we can write

$$
G=\bigsqcup_{g\in\mathcal I}PgP\quad\text{and}\quad|G|=\sum_{g\in\mathcal I}|PgP|,
$$

where $\mathcal I$ is a complete set of double coset representatives for $G$. Now, the proof splits the summation into two separate summations:

$$
|G|=\sum_{g\in\text N(P)}|PgP|+\sum_{g\not\in\text N(P)}|PgP|,
$$

where $\text N(P)$ denotes the normalizer of $P$ in $G$. This part is fine. In the first summation, which extends over $g\in\text N(P)$, we know that each term $PgP=P(Pg)=Pg$. So the first summation can be expressed as

$$
\sum_{g\in\text N(P)}|PgP|=\sum_{g\in\text N(P)}|Pg|.
$$

This part is also clear to me. But now the proof asserts that, since the summation extends over distinct cosets of $P$ in $\text N(P)$, then $\sum_{g\in\text N(P)}|Pg|=|\text N(P)|$. I don't understand two things:

1. It's clear that each $Pg$  is a distinct coset, since the original summation was over distinct coset representatives. But why is it that $\sum_{g\in\text N(P)}|Pg|=|\text N(P)|$, necessarily? This might be a dumb question, but it is generally true that if $H<G$, then

$$
|G|=\sum_{g\in\mathcal I}|Hg|\quad\text{entails}\quad|H|=\sum_{g\in \mathcal I\cap H}|Hg|\,?
$$

2. Why did we have to rewrite $PgP$ as $Pg$? If the answer to my first question is yes, and the double cosets $PgP$ partition $P$ anyway, could we not have written

$$
|\text N(P)|=\sum_{g\in\text N(P)}|PgP|\,?
$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already recalled that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and we have that $g_1,\ldots,g_k$ is a complete set of coset representatives for $H$ in $G$, then
$$G = \mathop{\amalg}\limits_{i=1}^n Hg,\qquad\text{and}\qquad |G|=\sum_{i=1}^n |Hg_i|.$$

So now, consider $P$ as a subgroup of $N(P)$. If $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ are the coset representatives for $P$ in $N(P)$, then we will certainly have that $\sum_{i=1}^n |Pg| = |N(P)|$.

So the only question is whether double coset representatives for $P$ in $N(P)$ coincide with coset representatives of $P$ in $N(P)$. You already noted that if $g\in N(P)$, then the double coset $PgP$ is equal to the right coset $Pg$. Conversely, if $h\in N(P)$, then $Ph = PPh = Phh^{-1}Ph = PhP$. Thus, every right coset of $P$ in $N(P)$ corresponds to one of the double cosets you have. That’s why you can assert the equality.

As to why he rewrites... in part because you are more used to cosets; here it is clear that they are the cosets of $P$ in $N(P)$, and so the sum is $|N(P)|$, as is usually the case for any subgroup and group.

But mostly he rewrote because he wanted to count how many elements there are in $PxP$; while every coset has the same size, the same does not hold for double cosets.

The double coset $HeH$ has cardinality $|H|$, but if $x\notin N(H)$, then in general $HxH$ has different cardinality. E.g., in $S_3$, the double coset $H(123)H$ of $H=\{e,(12)\}$ consists of $e(123)e=(123)$, $e(123)(12)= (13)$, $(12)(123)e = (23)$, and $(12)(123)(12) = (132)$, so $H(123)H$ has four elements. )

So he first calculated how many elements there are in $PxP$ when $x\notin N(P)$; and then he rewrites to easily calculate how many elements there are in $PxP$ when $x\in N(P)$: since in that case $PxP=Px$, then there are exactly $|P|$ elements.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and example about double cosets possibly having different sizes - that was illuminating. One followup question: Let $K<H<G$. If $\{g_1,\dots g_n\}$ is a complete set of coset representatives for $K$ in $G$, we know $|G|=\sum_i^n|Kg_i|$. Now, if $\{g_{j_1},\dots,g_{j_k}\}$ are the subset of $\{g_1,\dots,g_n\}$ which are in $H$, how do know for sure that this set is "complete" and $|H|=\sum_{i=1}^k|Kg_{j_i}|$?

Comment: @buffle: If $h$ is any element of $H$, then there must be some $k$ with $h\in Kg_k$; but then $g_k\in Kh\subseteq KH=H$. Thus, elements of $H$ are in cosets represented by elements of $H$, and the latter must form a complete set of representatives (there cannot be any that are not disjoint by the initial choice).

Comment: Perfect, now I understand. Thank you for your clear explanation.